# img tag inside a tag or giving background image to a tag which one is better

Tags: css, tags, image

Considering SEO which one is better.
IMG tag inside a tag or giving background image to the a tag.
Please suggest which one suits well for seo purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If image is relevant to content

For **SEO** - keep image in `HTML` and give a relevant name to image and describe the image in `alt` attribute.

If image is purely decorative than keep in CSS.

**Edit**

And read this article to understand the proper use with link

http://webaim.org/blog/alt-text-and-linked-images/

Comment: Don't describe images in alt attributes, provide real alternative content. e.g. "ACME" is much better than "ACME logo" when you have an image of a company logo to indicate something about the company. The fact it is their logo is beside the point.